# Keras NN producing results with good variability prediction but poor magnitude prediction

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm currently using keras (tensorflow) to create a feed-forward neural network to predict a sales value.  When I look at the test set comparing predicted vs real sales values a fit line ends up having a good R squared value but a low slope value.  So it's predicting the variability in the data correctly, but not predicting the magnitude of the data.  When I look at the data in smaller subsets, the underprediction is consistent.  Has anybody had experience with this or have an idea what could cause this?  I have a feeling it may be a data bias/normalization issue.

Comment: Have you compared the range of your final activation function with your actual data?

Comment: I have not. Can you expand on this with regards to how it could cause this problem?

Comment: Sigmoid only outputs between 0 and 1. Tanh only outputs between -1 and 1, etc.

Comment: I have changed it to test this and it doesn't appear to be the issue.  Test set values are still consistently between 20 and 30 percent of what their real values are.